# What did @Shog9 mean by this?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderators, frozen-rooms

SciFi.SE's primary chatroom [Mos Eisley was recently nuked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/valorum-himarm-poisoned-this-room-it-is-defunct) and the last message posted there by @Shog9 is:

> If any moderator un-freezes this room, they will have hell to pay.,

Seeing this, I am curious what he meant by this. What are his superpowers which can inflict damage to a mod and where is he willing to go?

I am sure, he doesn't have nuclear codes to nuke the IP location of that mod. Would he strip that mod of powers? Or, would he ban him? Or, would he make the Stack Exchange sue that mod in real?

I am just curious, nothing more. When we say those things in real world, we have options of punching or public shaming that person or so. These things aren't applicable here, of course.

Comment: Why does it matter what form the "hell to pay" will take? Morbid curiosity not withstanding.

Comment: Um...at the very least he can make moderators into non-moderators at a push of a button. Not sure there is a higher price to pay than your moderatorship itself. I don't know what else you exactly expect from "hell to pay" if not actual hell then.

Comment: Its worth reading the related meta.SF posts - this is a pretty serious incident, and quite a bit of the CM team (including the folk who manage the managers are in on it.). Without context you're not going to understand how *serious* the matter is.

Answer (score 18):

It's a more colorful way of telling all Chat SE moderators that we're not supposed to unfreeze that room under any circumstances. Some kind of notice is necessary here as a few hundred users have the ability to unfreeze that room (e.g. a user could try to convince a moderator that is not aware of the full history to unfreeze that room).

Answer (score 7):

Though this better fits some English site of SE, I'll try to answer using my common sense.

Shog was just pissed off, big time.

He did not mean what he wrote literally.

What I take from this is that if a moderator will unfreeze the room, Shog will simply take the diamond away from that moderator. Maybe warning them first, maybe even without a warning, since such a warning is already given in that very message.

Shog will **not** do any of these:

- Harm the moderator physically.
- Locate moderator location IRL and nuke it.
- Publicly shame the moderator for other things they might have done in the past.

Comment: However, it deviates from the [Be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) model of SE. I don't know if it is not applicable to Community Managers.

Comment: @San this indeed does not apply to those who enforce the rules, who sometimes have no choice, they need to be harsh in order to be heard and not ignored. Being nice in those cases won't deter users from keeping their bad behavior.

Comment: I agree, that means it is not applicable to CMs.

Comment: How in the world could Shog physically harm a moderator?

Comment: @Pritt many ways. Knife, club, gun, fists...

Comment: He may not shame mods, but he certainly went out of his way to shame two users when he renamed the room.

Comment: @WadCheber so? Looks like they just deserved it.

Comment: So the oft repeated rules about not discussing suspended people or shaming them don't apply if you're angry enough and you're a CM?

Comment: I just thought community managers would be less petty.

Comment: @Wad IMO being nice won't deter such users from doing such things. Sometimes the only way to fight fire is with fire, and that's one of those times.

Comment: I might buy that if the two users in question hadn't already been banned from chat forever.  If they can never chat again, calling them out serves no constructive purpose and comes across as childish.

Comment: @Wad it deters other users, from doing similar things.

Comment: Not really.  Certainly not as much as *closing the room forever*.  This decision - particularly the renaming - has alienated much of our primary user base and most of our mods.  It wasn't a deterrent, it was a temper tantrum.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Over the Internet, magically throwing a grenade from StackOverFlow office to the Mods home, thousands of miles away?

Comment: @Pritt pretty sure Shog can do that if he really wants to, but my point here is that he does not want. :)